# Sikuli - FindFailed in very simple script

Tags: sikuli

I am new to Sikuli and am trying it out with a very simple script that looks like this...

[image]

When I run this it almost immediatley returns the following error...

```
[error] script [ Untitled ] stopped with error in line 2
[error] FindFailed ( can not find 1476712210350.png in R[0,0 1366x768]@S(0) )
[error] --- Traceback --- error source first line: module ( function ) statement 55: Region ( wait ) Line 2189, in file Region.java
[error] --- Traceback --- end -------------
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

When you use **wait(image,time)**, the program try to find the image in the region. If the program can't find the image, throw an error message and finish the execution. To deal with this error, try to use the next:

```
# First, check if image exists for n seconds
# Pattern and similar, set how much similar your image will be.
if exists(Pattern("GoogleSearch.png").similar(0.8), time_in_seconds):
    if exists(Pattern("FeelingLucky.png").similar(0.6), time_in_seconds):
        click(Pattern("FeelingLucky.png").similar(0.6))
```

As you can see, the value of similar set the percent between 0 and 1.

PD: My english isn't too good. I'm still learning ;)

Comment: Don't worry, your English is perfect. :-) 
+1 for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think Michael is giving a great example, but maybe a little bit difficult to understand if you are completly new to Sikuli.

```
openApp(r"<Fill_In_Your_Path_Etc>")
while not exists("GoogleSearch.png"):
    #Wait 1 second, then check again for the image. 
    wait(1)
click("ButtonLucky.png")
```

The above code should work as well, but be aware of infinite loops. 
 
The code above will wait forever if image `GoogleSearch.png` is not found. 
 
To make sure you don't create an infinite loop you could add a `break` after the loop runed x number of times.